# how to copy multiple checked rows in html via JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML blade page that contains a table and I'm trying to copy the checked rows in HTML by using the following script:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

        $('#checkAll').on('change', function() {
            $('.rowCheckbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

        const copySelectedButton = document.getElementById('copySelected');
        copySelectedButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            const selectedRows = document.querySelectorAll('input.rowCheckbox:checked');
            let textToCopy = '';

            selectedRows.forEach(row => {
                const text = row.getAttribute('data-clipboard-text');
                textToCopy += text + '\n';
            });

            if (selectedRows.length > 0) {
                copyToClipboard(textToCopy);

                iziToast.success({
                    title: 'Done',
                    message: 'Done',
                    position: 'bottomRight'
                });
            } else {
                iziToast.info({
                    title: 'No Records',
                    message: 'No Records',
                    position: 'bottomRight'
                });
            }
        });

        function copyToClipboard(text) {
            const tempTextarea = document.createElement('textarea');
            tempTextarea.value = text;
            document.body.appendChild(tempTextarea);
            tempTextarea.select();
            document.execCommand('copy');
            document.body.removeChild(tempTextarea);
        }
    });
</script>
```

it's working but returns Null values in each row, in the other saying I got the copied results but I don't got the values for each row I got instead

null

null

null

null

null

if I checked 5 rows

I'm using Laravel and that code inside view.

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="width: 5%;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"></th>
            <th style="width: 50%;">agent</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">curr</th>
            <th style="width: 20%;">ras</th>
            <th style="width: 5%;">copy</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($result as $x)
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowCheckbox"></td>
            <td>{{ $x->AccName }}</td>
            <td>{{ $x->AccCurrName }}</td>
            <td>{{ number_format($x->AccRaseed, 0) }}</td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info btncopy" data-clipboard-text="agent: {{ $x->AccName }}&#13;curr: {{ $x->AccCurrName }}&#13;ras: {{ number_format($x->AccRaseed, 0) }}">
                    <i class="las la-copy"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

what's the problem please

Comment: `const text = row.getAttribute('data-clipboard-text');` - `row` is one of your checked checkboxes here, those are what you are looping over. Your checkboxes do not have a `data-clipboard-text` attribute, so you are getting undefined back from this line.

Comment: @CBroe so how to solve that please

Comment: Either you go up from the currently clicked checkbox to the parent `tr` element, and then select the button element in there ... Or put the data attribute onto the checkbox element to begin with. (If you need it on the button as well, that would probably make less sense, keeping the data redundantly in two places. Putting it onto the `tr` in the first place then, so that both for the button and the checkbox you only have to traverse up to the row, would also be a option then.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added variable to keep the data:

```
@php
    $lineBreak = "\n";
    $clipboardText = "الاسم: " . $x->AccName . $lineBreak . "العملة: " . $x->AccCurrName . $lineBreak . "الرصيد: " . number_format($x->AccRaseed, 0). $lineBreak;
    @endphp
```

and then I changed the checkbox to be:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="rowCheckbox" data-clipboard-text="{{ $clipboardText }}"></td>
```